# How to run update sql natively and not calling JPA PreUpdate

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

In my model class `Account`, in the jpa `@PreUpdate` I am setting the value of the field `lastUpdateDate` to the current date and time.

The Class model looks like this:

```
class Account {

    private String m_id;
    private String m_fullName;

    ...

    private Date m_indexDate;
    private Date m_lastUpdateDate;

    @Id
    public String getId() {
        return m_id;
    }

    @Audited
    public String getFullName() {
        return m_fullName;
    }

    public String getIndexDate() {
        return m_indexDate;
    }

    public String getLastUpdateDate() {
        return m_indexDate;
    }

    ...

    @PreUpdate
    void preUpdate() {
        setLastUpdateDate(new Date());
    }
}
```

I also have `indexDate` which is updated after every successfull sync/update with Elasticsearch.

Now, because of `@PreUpdate` ... `lastUpdateDate` always gets updated whenever I update the `indexDate` via JPA save or update... or even via @Query (native = true).

Is there a way to update indexDate (via native sql update) or other way but I will not hit `@PreUpdate` so that `lastUpdateDate` will not get updated?

I want to update `indexDate` without getting `lastUpdateDate` updated. `@PreUpdate` is working fine.. I jsut dont want to call this on `indexDate` update which is triggered only after successful update/sync with elasticsearch.

Comment: Just write  a query and execute it? Doesn't even have to be SQL could be JPQL as well.

Comment: I tried running on both sql (native) and jpql via `@Query` as wells as via jpa Query.executeUpdate() but still all of them access/hit the `@PreUpdate` and `lastUpdateDate` still gets updated

Comment: I think as long as the update is via jpa, it will still call @PreUpdate, I am thinking is there any other non-jpa way for me to update index_date (and call PreUpdate)

Comment: If you need to use @PreUpdate then you can add some logic (with transient properties) to your preUpdate method. Otherwise you will need to use Event Listeners what makes me think that probably it would be better to rethink about this requirement and implementation.

Comment: It won't call `@PreUpdate` because there is no entity to be update just a query to be translated to SQL. When executing a JPQL it will not, first retrieve the entities matching the query, trying to deduct based on the query what to update and then update the entities. It will just in one go translate the JPQL to SQL, so no `@PreUpdate` will be involved here.

Comment: @BorgyManotoy are you sure native queries or jpql queries update trigger the @PreUpdate? (i would not expect that) if you are can you confirm that in the same transaction you don't load and change Accounts?

Comment: I think `lastUpdateDate` is set/called somewhere in the codes. I need to check on this and maybe I can put the logic there.